# Как исправить потерю качества при уменьшении размера Bitmap?

Tags: android, java, изображения, bitmap

Здравствуйте!  
Уменьшаю размер bitmap вот таким образом:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(someImageStream);
int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();          
float scale = 0.5f;            
final Bitmap scaledBitmap =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg,(int)(width*scale), (int)(height*scale),true);
```

Однако качество при показе сжатого изображения оставляет желать лучшего.  Подскажите, как делать правильно?

Comment: В свое время похожую задачу решил очень просто - был отдельный сервер, который трансформировал картинки. А клиент подгружал через него. Это было очень удобно, так как сервер брал картинки не от клиента, а напрямую, а клиент только запрашивал их по номерам. Плюс ко всему, исходные картинки были в самых разных форматах и размерах.

Comment: да, такой вариант конечно решит проблему, но когда я задавал вопрос, не было возможности править сервер, так как сроки были ограчинены. я надеялся есть другое решение есть. Ведь андроид сам же решает данную проблему,  например, если положить картинку в ресурсы только для xhdpi, то он ее нормально сожмет и отобразит на маленьких экранах.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821488/bad-image-quality-after-resizing-scaling-bitmap).

Comment: не, такое я перепробывал уже.

Answer (score 1):

Советуют уменьшать не в один шаг, а за несколько шагов. Например пять раз по -10% на каждый шаг.

Comment: учитывая, что каждый шаг будет давать свою погрешность, то чем больше шагов, тем больше погрешность.

Answer (score 0):

```
Paint paint_name = new Paint();
paint_name.setFitlerBitmap(true);
```

И потом рисуете оба битмапа с помощью этой краски